# javascript closure - array, cannot understand the outcomes (simple ex)

Tags: javascript, closures

```
    var arr = []
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        arr[i] = function(){
            return i;
        }
    }
    for(var index in arr){
        document.write(arr[index]())};
```

what i expected to see was 12345, but the outcome is 55555

let me explain my logic below by using '//'

```
    var arr = []                   // creating array new object
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){            
        arr[i] = function(){
            return i;
        }             
    // arr = [function(){return 0}, function(){return 1}, function(){return 2}, function(){return 3}, function(){return 4}
    }
    for(var index in arr){
        document.write(arr[index]())};

    // outcome is 12345
```

i`ve already read the article 
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example),

but still cannot understand..

Comment: i didn`t duplicate any other articles, that code is for tutorials`s video,

Comment: You could also try [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: thanks for advice RobG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your **for loop**, `var i` is not block-scoped. Meaning, you can access `i` outside the loop. So, after you created the functions inside the loop which **returns i**, and execute those functions outside, it will have `i = 5`, because that's the last value you assigned to `i`. You need to use `let` instead of `var` to have a block-scoped variable which you would use in your loop.

Comment: thanks, but still wondering about this issue, i thought that arr would be determined, i mean, 

arr = [function(){return 0}, function(){return 1}, function(){return 2}, function(){return 3}, function(){return 4},

but in your explanation,
arr = [function(){return i}, function(){return i}, function(){return i}, function(){return i}, function(){return i},

i instead of concrete numbers,
later refering the i=5.

am i undertstand correctly..?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: thank you so much, 
little bothering extra question,, 
why not arr = [function(){return 0}, function(){return 1}, function(){return 2}, function(){return 3}, function(){return 4} ?

isn`t (return i`s i) same as (for var i`s i) ? 

why still remaining just i? instead of concrete numbers?

Comment: Because you are just **defining** functions, not executing it inside the loop. By the time you execute a function, it looks for the value of `i`, which in your case has the most recent value of 5.

Comment: ahha... just because of that yet-function-call? i was confused because the arr[i]`s i is increasing, reflecting the 1,2,3,4,5 otherwise return i`s i still remaining just i ... thanks for your help and i really appreciate it,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i is 5 by the time any of those functions is called

By the way, I'd expect 01234 as the output

In new browsers (not internet exploder) you can simply change the var i to let i

```js
var arr = []
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
    arr[i] = function(){
        return i;
    }
}
for(var index in arr){
    console.log(arr[index]())
}
```

but that doesn't help internet exploder - so, running this through a transplier ([babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/) for example) you get

```js
"use strict";

var arr = [];

var _loop = function _loop(i) {
    arr[i] = function () {
        return i;
    };
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    _loop(i);
}

for(var index in arr){
    console.log(arr[index]())
}
```

Comment: thanks for help! i appreciate it